# Get the Count of a List of unknown type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am calling a function that returns an object and in certain circumstances this object will be a List.

A GetType on this object might gives me:

```
{System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Class1]}
```

or

```
{System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Class2]}
```

etc

I don't care what this type is, all I want is a Count.

I've tried:

```
Object[] methodArgs=null;
var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Count");
int count = (int)method.Invoke(list, methodArgs);
```

but this gives me an AmbiguousMatchException which I can't seem to get around without knowing the type.

I've tried casting to IList but I get:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[ClassN]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'1[System.Object]'.

***UPDATE***

Marcs answer below is actually correct. The reason it wasn't working for me is that I have:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

at the top of my file. This means I was always using the Generic versions of IList and ICollection. If I specify System.Collections.IList then this works ok.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Cast it to ICollection and use that `.Count`

```
using System.Collections;

List<int> list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 100));

ICollection collection = list as ICollection;
if(collection != null)
{
  Console.WriteLine(collection.Count);
}
```

Comment: Don't I still need a type <T> though?

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but this gives me: Error 1 Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>' requires '1' type arguments

Comment: @Chris, List<T> directly implements ICollection (non-generic) which has a `.Count` property.  No type required. Added sample code for clarity.

Comment: @Chris, I tried to make it a completely stand-alone example, hope that helps.

Comment: If I specify System.Collections.ICollection or System.Collections.IList - this actually works now. Because I had using System.Collections.Generic; it was using the generic versions of these interfaces. Thanks

Comment: Good job Marc!
Chris, please mark as solution, so I can find it if I ever bump into this (I use List<T> all the time in my code, so....)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
var property = typeof(ICollection).GetProperty("Count");
int count = (int)property.GetValue(list, null);
```

assuming you want to do this via reflection that is.

Comment: I like this, but this only works when the list actually _is_ an ICollection type.  I don't think this is always the case in the OP's question.

Comment: Admittedly it is a bit hard to tell, but since the examples given are both `List<T>` this works for the given cases. However, looking at the accepted answer it seems there's really no reason to use reflection in this case. If reflection isn't needed it is much easier to just cast to the appropriate type.

Comment: did not work for me: "Using the generic type 'ICollection<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Answer (score 0):

Use GetProperty instead of GetMethod

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var countMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(method => method.Name == "Count" && method.IsStatic && method.GetParameters().Length == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help...

```
        if (responseObject.GetType().IsGenericType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((dynamic) responseObject).Count);
        }
```